# save string to file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-io, csv, save

I've got a iteration (in my view):

```
(1..@count.to_i).each do |i|
   ...doing things...
  @bigtable << @result[0..result.length-2]
end
```

Every @result is a string. @bigtable has every @result from iterations.
Now what I want:
I want to save content from the @bigtable (after clickin a button) to .csv file (and choose where to save it on my hdd). And I want do it like every @result from @bigtable is in its own single line, like this (pseudo code):

```
@result string from @bigtable[0]
@result string from @bigtable[1]
etc.
```

Please, help

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To transform your array into a string you can do :

```
@bigtable.join("\n")
```

To write this string into a file :

```
File.open("path/to/file", "w") { |file| file.write @bigtable.join("\n") }
```

And that's it!

BTW:

```
@result[0..result.length-2] == @result[0..-2]
```

Comment: You must create an action to one of your controllers, and call this action when your button is clicked, basically.

Comment: ok,I've got something like this in my `generators_controller`: `def savefile
    @bigtable.join("\n")
    File.open("path/to/file", "w") { |file| file.write @bigtable.join("\n") }
  end` and how bind it to the  button in my view(html code)? can You help me?

Comment: It's very basic stuff, you should take a look to a RoR tutorial. Basically you must create a route to reach your new action from your view. Be careful, if your @bigtable variable has been create in the view (not really MVC...) you must pass it via parameter thanks to a form, something like that.

Comment: thanks! I forgot about this (via parameter thing) and mine code doesn't work, but thanks to You, I'll fix it. Thanks again!

Comment: unfortunately, I can't go through with that problem, could You ( @john-mckey ) help me? here is the link for a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749142/saving-file-after-passing-parameter