# saving file after passing parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, string, file-io, save

Here is the parent question: [save string to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743131/save-string-to-file/8743229#8743229)
I want to pass the parameter which will be saved in file(.csv) after clicking button.

@bigtable is a table with strings in each row.
Here is the code in my show.html.erb:

```
...some code here...
<%= form_tag do %>
  <% text_field_tag, id = "bigtable", value = @bigtable.to_s %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Zapisz' %>
<% end %>
```

and my controller method:

```
 def savefile
    @bigtable = param[:bigtable]
    @bigtable.join("\n")
    File.open("path/to/file", "w") { |file| file.write @bigtable.join("\n") }
  end
```

But mine code doesn't work :/
I want to save @bigtable strings to file. Each row record of the table is a new line of the file. And I want to save file without redirecting current page anywhere but completely don't know why:( Please help.

---

okay, I know why it doesn't work - I shoud add some new route to initialize `savefile` method - but how do it without redirecting/refreshing current page with results? plz help

Comment: Could you elaborate on _doesn't work_? What's actually happening? What doesn't work? Are you sure that `savefile` is getting called?

Comment: just doesn't work - after clicking the button it redirects me to current page again and nothing else - no saving file etc. :/

Comment: If that's your actual code, you might want to add an action to the `form_tag` and a route so that you'll actually end up on the `savefile` action in the controller when clicking the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution - to not write double post here is the link to the topic with the answer: [saving variable to file and downloading it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947214/saving-variable-to-file-and-downloading-it/8961816#8961816)

Answer (score 1):

Use `<%= form_tag(url, :remote => true) do %>` to make the call with Ajax, so your page will not be redirected. Use your server logs to see if the request is executed (if you want to get the result of the ajax call in your page, look at http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/).