# saving variable to file and downloading it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, button, methods, download, saving-data

I've got a problem with my previous question. Nobody can't help me so I'll try to write better this time what I want:

- I've got a `generators#show` view, and in this view I want to do
  everything without refreshing page after clicking a button etc.
- I've got a variable (it is nowhere stored - just dynamically put on
  the site): `@bigtable`, which is actually an array of strings
- I have a button placed in this view: `<%= form_tag do %><%= submit_tag 'Save it' %><% end %>`
- If someone will click on that button I want to pop up an window and
  he could set where he want to save a txt file (and set filename),
  filled with all `@bigtable` array records.

For couple days I think I've tried everything but I don't really understand how to solve it. Could someone, please write here what methods in model and controller I should write? And all required routes? I'll really appreciate any help.
My previous thread (but please do not send me there or give same answers like there): [saving file after passing parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749142/saving-file-after-passing-parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally I've found a solution:

```
def savefile
    @generator = Generator.new(params[:generator])
    @bigtable = Rails.cache.read("pass")
    doc = "wyniki.csv"
    File.open(doc, "w"){ |f| f << @bigtable}
    send_file(doc, :type => 'text; charset=utf-8')
  end
```